# How To Gracefully Restart Celery

Tags: python, celery, supervisord

We're using Celery with Pylons on Python 2.7 with Supervisord. Every time the app is restarted, the Celery instance loses MySQL connection and results in errors like:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

Here's the supervisord config for the celery instance:

```
[program:celery_default]
command=/path/python/bin/newrelic-admin run-program /path/python/bin/celery worker -Q default -c 10 ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
environment=P2S_INI="/path/production.ini",NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE="newrelic_celery.ini",P2S_NEW_RELIC_ENABLED=1
directory=/path/some
process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true              ; retstart at unexpected quit (default: true)
startsecs=15                  ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
startretries=10                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
user=somuser ;
nodaemon=false              ; run supervisord as a daemon
```

How can I avoid such connection errors and have celery restart gracefully? I have also tried sending stop signal as HUP. That also did not help.